# Error during rendering of region "Oracle Application Express"

Tags: oracle-apex

We use Oracle Application Express. Sometimes after opening a browser, going to Oracle Application Express and entering a workspace, login and password, we get the error:

[image]

You can see our current version in the right side of the screenshot below.

It has been showing since January. Before we didn't have it.

What we've tried to solve the problem:

- we tried to restart the server with sessions. We use Apache Tomcat.
- we tried to clean sessions

Comment: Hi.. I'm facing the same issue.. Getting "Error during rendering of Region" error. Can you let me know how if the issue is solved for you? and what are the steps followed to resolve? I'm using Oracle APEX 21.2 version. TIA Shan

Answer (score 0):

With the information you are providing it is not possible to answer your question. It's unlikely that restarting the webserver (I have no idea what "restarting the server with sessions" means but I assume that is what you mean).

From you description it seems you're an end user of an application. Someone with developer access needs to have a look at the application and check what code is running when the region with the name "Oracle Application Express" on that page is rendered. That code is errorring out - there should be more info in the error logs